# Quick overview OOP php to python?

Tags: python

I am from PHP and quick learn OOP Python base PHP 's knowledge
for example I have a class

```
<?php
class Cat{
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $color;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($value)
    {
        $this->name = $value;
    }

    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function setAge($value)
    {
        $this->age = $value;
    }

    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }

    public function setColor($value)
    {
        $this->color = $value;
    }

}
?>
```

What is equivalence to python OOP code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exact equivalent would be this:

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, name...):
        self.__name = name # __ make the var private
        ...

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def setName(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    ...
```

It will work, but you would never do that in Python. Here is why:

- Nothing is really private in Python, and you can always bypass restrictions using some tricks in this language. So you usually value more communication, doc and API that enforcing a behaviour.
- Accessing directly attribute is perfectly fine in Python. If you don't something special while getting or setting, then you don't write getters and setters. The best Python libs do this.
- You have something called 'properties' allowing you to change your mind after the fact. If in 1 month, you decide to do something while getting and setting a var, you can do it without changing you API.

Here is how you would to it in proper Python:

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

c = Cat('billy')
print c.name
# billy
c.name = 'kit'
print c.name
# kit
```

Now, what if suddenly you want to change your mind and ensure the name is always capitalize on when you store it ? You just add a property:

```
class Cat(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name # '_' is just a convention and does nothing

    @property # when you do cat.name, it will call this function
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter # when you do cat.name = x, it will call this function
    def name(self, name):
        """ Make the name uppercase when setting it """
        self._name = name.upper()
```

The code change, but from outside, it looks exactly the same:

```
c = Cat('billy')
print c.name
# BILLY
c.name = 'kit'
print c.name
# KIT
```

What are the main benefits?

- You don't have to write getter and setter most of the time, it same times and make the code shorter, hence easier to read.
- If you change your mind, you can always write ONE getter/setter. Only the one you need, not all the other ones. The API keeps looking consistent.

Answer (score 8):

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, color):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.color = color
```

No, I'm not joking.

1. Cut that getter/setter stuff, we have properties for a reason.
2. If you're going to have an attribute, you better have it all the time (i.e. from creation onward), or `AttributeError`s ensue. Even though PHP allows you to silence those (Python doesn't), they're a "code smell" in all languages.
3. In Python 2.x, you need to inherit from `object` (directly or indirectly) - otherwise, you get one of those nasty relicts from the past, old-style classes. Just don't bother with it. In Python 3, you don't need that boilerplate though (old-style classes are gone, everything inherits `object` if nothing else).
4. And this is important: **You won't learn Python (or any other language) by comparing a few short snippets.** Read a tutorial, some real code and Python questions on SO. Also, practice practice practice and have the code reviewed.

Comment: @kramthegram: Not anymore. The original version had a syntax error (missing colon) as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Cat(object):
   def __init__(self, name, age, color):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.color = color
```

Setters and getters are not usually used in Python; you can use [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) if you really need to do something fancy in them, so the interface won't ever need to change. Since the interface won't have to change if you decide to add 5 to every value you set, there's no need to type out the extra functions.

Incidentally, this isn't really OOP. It's just a C struct spelled out in Python. If you want to add OOP-style methods for, say, petting your cat, you can. Just add this to the class:

```
def pet(self):
    # Do whatever petting does to a cat.
    pass
```

Comment: `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` are more similar to PHP's `__get` and `__set`. In Python, we have properties to make the `get`/`set` identical to plain old attribute access/assignment to the outside.

Comment: @delnan: Whoops, you're right. I mixed the `property` up with `__getattr__`. I guess I don't use them very often. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has good answers, but I thought I'd include an example of the built-in `property` function.

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(sef, name, age, color):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age
        self._color = color

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    def get_age(self):
        return self._age    

    def set_age(self, value):
        self._age = value

    def get_color(self):
        return self._color

    def set_color(self, value):
        self._color = value

    name = property(get_name, set_name)
    age = property(get_age, set_age)
    color = property(get_color, set_color)
```

Comment: Using `property` as a decorator is actually even better. Also, you have syntax errors (colons missing) and slipped in a old-style class (is this the collective fail question? I did that too!). See http://www.ideone.com/akR5f for an example.

Comment: The problem is you shouldn't use the same name for property and variable. It will cause infinite loop. Use member name like `self._name` instead.

Comment: @delnan After reading up on the class changes I now am shaking my head at my old crappy python code. Also: I fixed my obvious errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is more like [this](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#property).

However, unless you need customized setter and getter, don't do this.